# Passing parameter during closing modal with ESC key

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-bootstrap

Is there a way to pass a parameter through the $modalInstance.dismiss when we close a modal using ESC key?
If user close properly using 'close', then I know I can use `$modalInstance.close(ctrl.anyParam)` and if I use cancel button I can use `$modalInstance.dismiss(ctrl.anyParam)`. This works fine since I have the promise from `$modalInstance.open` and depending on what user click, I can handle if the promise is resolved or rejected.

However, in the case where user click ESC, can I pass `ctrl.anyParam` so I can handle it in my reject promise? I created plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e9asYwjWxS7XFJvbLncp?p=preview) to describe my question.

Comment: For binding keys I recommend using mouse trap, https://craig.is/killing/mice in this case I would search for binding esc key, and the close/dismiss/hide event of this modal. Also the close event should have a triggered of the caller in order to know where it cames from, key press os something else.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you can do is to prevent the modal from closing with ESC by default by changing its config and register a key listener to perform the closing action (with the given parameter) programmatically, since there is no passing of parameters designated.